# Can Multiple orderBy and startAt Clauses in Firestore Replicate Inequality Filters on Multiple Fields?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to replicate inequalities on multiple fields in Firestore, which doesn't allow such queries. I attempted a workaround using orderBy and startAt.

Example (not allowed in Firestore):

```
query(
  collectionRef, 
  where('field1', '>=', value1), 
  where('field2', '>=', value2)
)
```

Workaround:

```
query(
  collectionRef, 
  orderBy('field1', 'asc'), 
  orderBy('field2', 'asc'), 
  startAt(value1, value2)
)
```

this workaround seems to work, but I have some questions:

1. Can this method fully replicate >= inequalities on multiple fields?
2. Is startAt considered an offset, affecting read costs?
3. Are there limitations or pitfalls to this approach?

Comment: Can you describe why first example is not working? Because it looks workable to me.

Comment: What's wrong with the first query? Why exactly doesn't work? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @AlexMamo here is an example:  let query_1 = query(collection(getFirestore(), 'tests'), where('field1', '>=', 0), where('field2', '>=', 1));
FirebaseError: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'field1' and 'field2'

Comment: So have you t ried to adjust the query according to the error message?